# React Native not updating icon when button is pressed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I'm using react-native-vector-icons, and I want to change the icon when I press the button.

```
const {favorites, toggleFavorite} = useFavorites();
const isFavorite = favorites.includes(value);

  return (
...
<Button
   icon={
          <Icon
            name={isFavorite ? 'favorite' : 'favorite-border'}
            size={24}
            color={theme.colors.text.contrast}
          />
        }
        onPress={() => toggleFavorite(value)}
        type="clear"
      />

export const useFavorites = (): {
  favorites: string[];
  toggleFavorite: (lineNumber: string) => Promise<void>;
} => {
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const readFavorites = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(FAVORITES_KEY);
      setFavorites(value ? value.split(',') : []);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const toggleFavorite = async (lineNumber: string) => {
    let newFavorites = favorites;

    if (favorites.includes(lineNumber)) {
      newFavorites = newFavorites.filter(favorite => favorite !== lineNumber);
    } else {
      newFavorites.push(lineNumber);
    }

    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(FAVORITES_KEY, newFavorites.join(','));
      setFavorites(newFavorites);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    readFavorites();
  }, []);

  return {
    favorites,
    toggleFavorite,
  };
};
```

When I press the button, the value of isFavorite is toggled correctly. Also it works when isFavorite is true initially. It doesn't work the other way around. What am I missing here?

EDIT: Added useFavorites for more context

Comment: what is `value`?

Comment: value is a string that will be added/removed from the favorites array

Comment: How are you importing the library?

Comment: Can you show useFavorites detail?

Comment: import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you add item wrong way. You cannot mutate state directly. Just update like this:

```
  if (favorites.includes(lineNumber)) {
    newFavorites = newFavorites.filter(favorite => favorite !== lineNumber);
  } else {
    newFavorites = [...favorites, lineNumber]
  }
```